# Removing Items From an array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays

```
$alpha=array('a','b','c','d','e','f');

$index=array('2','5');
```

I need to remove the items in the first array that has the index from the second array.

(Remove c-index is 2 and f-index is 5)

So that the returned array is

{'a','b','d','e'}

How can i do this using PHP?
Thanks

Edit

Actually I need the final array as follows

```
[0]=>a
[1]=>b
[2]=>d
[3]=>e
```

Unsetting will return the array with same indexes

```
0 => string 'a' 
2 => string 'c' 
3 => string 'd' 
4 => string 'e'
```

Comment: If you're in this for the Karma, get over yourself. Help the community, not the user.

Comment: @Matt It's nice to show appreciation when somebody solves your problem. Not required by any means, but nice. If a user doesn't care enough to do that, or doesn't know how the community works, then *that* user isn't adding any of value to the community. Besides, it's not like I'm telling him to accept **my** answer (I don't even have one) or anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach ($index as $key) {
    unset($alpha[$key]);
}
```

had it as array_unset() before.

Comment: `array_unset` must be a [new function not yet created](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php)...

Comment: Gives me an error

Fatal error: Call to undefined function array_unset()

Comment: Sorry, I corrected the answer. It's unset() not array_unset()

Comment: instead of array_unset() use unset($alpha[$key])

Comment: I disagree - he can use this code for ANY array that contains ANY number of indices. Don't be a lazy coder.

Comment: The best code is: var_dump(array_diff_key($alpha, array_flip($index)));

Answer (score 3):

Please, try this for more performance:

```
var_dump(array_diff_key($alpha, array_flip($index)));
```

Answer (score 2):

Another method (in case `$alpha` or `$index` happen to be big and you want to keep it all on php):

```
function remove_keys($array, $indexes = array()){
  return array_intersect_key($array, array_diff(array_keys($array),$indexes));
}
```

[IDEOne Example](http://ideone.com/P03lT)

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through the keys in your `$index` array and remove the corresponding key during the iteration using [`unset()`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php):

```
<?php
$alpha=array('a','b','c','d','e','f');  
$index=array('2','5'); 

foreach ($index as $key) {     
    unset($alpha[$key]);
} 

var_dump($alpha);
?>
```

Output:

```
array(4) { [0]=> string(1) "a" [1]=> string(1) "b" [3]=> string(1) "d" [4]=> string(1) "e" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
$array = array('a', 'b','c');
unset($array[0]);
$array = array_values($array); //reindexing
```

Comment: This will only unset the value at array index 0. It won't shift anything in the array, you'll just have array(2) { [1]=> string(1) "b" [2]=> string(1) "c" }